# Is there a JSON schema or data model for Spring Boot Actuator REST interfaces?

Tags: spring-boot, jsonschema

Spring Boot Actuator provides useful REST interfaces, such as '/health', which can return detailed health status information for a service. This format seems useful, and I would like to implement this same response in other microservices (that are not based on Java) to report health information. In general, it would be useful if I could treat the json returned by the Spring Boot Actuator as if it were a standard, or at least if it had a published schema/data model.

The documentation gives detailed examples of the json response to expect from a health endpoint, but no link to json schema or data model - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/actuator-api/html/#health-retrieving

Is such a schema available? (If not, are there other similar standardized REST interfaces that report health in a semi-standard format?) Thanks.

Comment: Spring boot actuator is library/framework to provide SpringBoot Applications heath info, health info can vary with the different framework(i never tried other till now). Json are schema less unlike XML where we can define XML schema by dtd or xsd.

Comment: @Swaraj True, but there are some basic health indicators that apply to almost any service, such as the basic status of "UP" and disk space. I'm hoping there is something like a 'Swagger Data Model' or 'Json Schema'. Swagger Data Models are actually supersets of Json Schema, I believe. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/ and https://json-schema.org/specification.html. Thanks.